# Symfony working with multiple bundle and uploading bundle to server

Tags: php, symfony

I have two problems with symfony. First one is, if I have two bundles created, only the first created bundle is shown when I go to `localhost/symfony/web/app_dev.php/` As of now, I have the two bundles in my `src/` both bundles are registered in the kernel, routes added and everything. But, I can only see the first created bundle, I don't know what to do, to see the second bundle in action.

Second problem is that, when I want to upload my finished symfony project, I can't see know how.  Like, do I tell `.htaccess` to treat the `app_dev.php` files as index files, and to hide the folder name `symfony` from the URL, so that the `mysite.com/symfony/web/app_dev.php` to show as `mysite.com/index.php` because, I don't really get it.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with "I can only see the first". What do you mean with "see"?

Comment: I can only see one bundle in action. I have two bundles in `src` file. BundleA and BudleB. So, app_dev.php always shows me, BundleA, I want to know, what to do to switch, so that I can see BundleB

Comment: What does means "always show me"?

Comment: It means, when I go to `app_dev.php` I can only see BundleA. I need to configure Symfony to show me BundleB.

Comment: You should go to the docs and learn about the fundamentals of symfony:  http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_fundamentals.html

Comment: I think you have two routes with the same path. Can you check this?

Comment: Nope. `App/config/routing/yml` shows two difference paths

Comment: I still dont understand what do you mean with "see".

Answer (score 1):

To "see second bundle in action", point your browser to some route of such bundle.

To be sure its routes have been registered, run:

```
$ php app/console router:debug
```

and see if they appear in the list.

---

Regarding deploying, you should read [this topic](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment-tools.html).

Keep in mind that `app_dev.php` is meant for development environment, and should not be used for production; included `.htaccess` already routes all requests to `app.php`.

In order to make `http://www.mysite.com/` your entry point, you should `/yourproject/web` be your webroot, or better use a symlink.

Comment: I don't understand the first answer. I did what you asked, and I can see two of my bundles mentioned. How does this help me to change if I want to see bundleA or bundleB which are both in my `src` files.

Comment: @XiiXii you don't "see" bundles. You use them to respond to HTTP requests from the client, e.g. bundle A answers to `/products`, bundle B to `/admin/edit/products`, that's up to you.

Answer (score -2):

**As the .htaccess part you way copy this into the .htaccess and put it in the root folder**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d



# DEV ENVIRONMENT #
RewriteRule ^$ symfony/web/app_dev.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ symfony/web/app_dev.php/$1 [QSA,L]

# PROD ENVIRONMENT #
RewriteRule ^$ symfony/web/app.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ symfony/web/app.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks, but after putting this in the `.htacess` file of `src` folder, then, how do I access the URL? Without the above code, I normally visit the site using `http://127.0.0.1/Symfony/web/app_dev.php` But, I am not sure, how I can access the site with the above code.

Comment: the above code it's not for the src folder change the .htacess of the src folder to deny from all  and the code above it's for the .htacess of the www folder outside symfony folder so you can visit your symfony website from http://127.0.0.1/